# Get the Product tag URL in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, taxonomy

I've been using product tags as brand for products in my shop. The following code which I have found online has been working fine (until the recent update of woocommerce and WP) to make a list on my "brands" page. It lists all brands under each specific category letter.

Suddenly no URLs are being generated, everything else is populated as it should. I really can't find the issue. I have tried to modify `get_terms` to `get_terms(array('taxonomy'=>'product_tag'))` but it's not working either.

This is my code:

```
$list = '';
$tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
$groups = array();
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
        $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
    }
    if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
        foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<div class="brand_category_container">';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<h4 class="cateogry_letter">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</h2>';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<ul>';
            foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
                $url = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
                $count = intval( $tag->count );
                $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
                $list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a class="category_links" href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
                }
            $list .= "\n\t" . '</ul></li>';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '</div>';
        }
    }
} else $list .= "\n\t" . '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';
```

on my product pages I list the brands with

```
$tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
?>
<div class="single_productbrand">
    <?php echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="brand_as">' . _n( '', '', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
</div>
```

and it works as it should

How can I get the URLs back?

Comment: What's the output when you var_dump($tags); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your code related to the `product tag terms links` is this line:

```
$url = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
```

> It needs to be replaced with [**`get_term_link()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) WordPress function that requires 2 arguments, the term object (or term ID) and the taxonomy.

As you might already now, Product Tags are a **custom taxonomy** `'product_tag'`…

Also in your code, even if it works, you should better have different variable names as you are using `$tags` variable name in 2 different parts with different values.

So your revisited and functional code will be:

```
$taxonomy = 'product_tag';
$tags = get_terms( $taxonomy );
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
        $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
    }
    if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
        $list = '';
        foreach( $groups as $letter => $letter_tags ) {
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<div class="brand_category_container">';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<h4 class="cateogry_letter">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</h2>';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<ul>';
            foreach( $letter_tags as $tag ) {
                $term_link = get_term_link( $tag->term_id, $taxonomy );
                $count = intval( $tag->count );
                $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
                $list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a class="category_links" href="' . $term_link . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
            }
            $list .= "\n\t" . '</ul></li>';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
else $list .= "\n\t" . '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';

// Output
echo $list;
```

This time the Urls are correct pointing to the right path...

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with pointing out the get_term_link(), as well as the other code improvements. It works as it should now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer `LoicTheAztec`, it helped me solving the problem but when i converted id with intval.

Note: let me tell you that when I updated the WordPress to 4.9 version this happened otherwise get_tag_link was working very fine with me.
Thanks again